# PyOpenGL on Ubuntu for Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, opengl, ubuntu, pyopengl, openglcontext

I am trying to install PyOpenGL and so far have tried the following ways:

1. $ pip install PyOpenGL PyOpenGL_accelerate
2. $ sudo python2.7 -m pip install PyOpenGL PyOpenGL_accelerate
3. Some variations of the above...
4. Installation from source.

Unfortunately I still can't run the following imports:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *  
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
```

I am getting the error message:

> unable to detect undefined names

Am I missing something? 
Do I need to install more packages?

Do I need to get OpenGLContext seperately? 
If so, how do I install that, since

```
pip install PyDispatcher PyVRML97 OpenGLContext
```

doesn't work either.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try sudo apt-get install python-opengl

Comment: How are you running your program

Comment: Hi, sry for the long wait. We decided to implement the project with a webGL engine. But the above should actually work. It seems that my pc is just weird with opengl.